# JQuery $.ajax output data format

Tags: jquery

I have the following code I am using to connect to a vender. When run, I am getting back a status code 0. When evaluating using Wireshark, I am finding that the request is failing because of the following:

**Error: The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'.**

I saw from the documentation that the dataType setting defines the incoming data only. How do I set the output as JSON?

(please excuse crude coding, this is only a shell at the moment)

```
    var key         = "xxxxxx";
        $.ajax({
            type        : "POST",
            dataType    : "JSON", 
            url         : "http://url",
            data        : {
                            "CityName":cty,
                            "FirmOrRecipient":name,
                            "LicenseKey":key,
                            "PrimaryAddressLine":s1,
                            "SecondaryAddressLine":s2,
                            "State":st,
                            "ZipCode":zip
            },
            success     : function (data, status, xhr) {
                var pretty = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4).replace( / /g, '&nbsp;').replace( /\n/g, '<br />');
                $('div#results').html(pretty);
            },
            error       : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    alert('ERROR: \n Failed to connect to PAV.\n Verify Network.');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    alert('ERROR: \n Requested page not found. [404]');
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    alert('ERROR: \n Internal Server Error [500].');
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    alert('ERROR: \n Requested JSON parse failed.');
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    alert('ERROR: \n Time out error.');
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    alert('ERROR: \n Ajax request aborted.');
                } else {
                    alert('ERROR: \n Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                }                    
            },
        });
```

Comment: For the output to be JSON, you would have to be sending JSON to the server. At the moment you are sending form params to the server instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your content type.

```
$.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        dataType    : "JSON", 
        contentType: 'application/json',
```

I would also make sure that you are sending valid json data ([jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

You Server should return JSON formatted output

**If you are using spring framework then you can annotate the method before the return type as**

```
@ResponseBody
```

So that spring will return it as JSON format.

But if you are using any other framework. Please use json jar files and try to construct JSON output format and return the same. Only then your ajax module would be able to read and process